# Blocking domain change @Visual Basic Web Browser

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've put a web browser on my form. My question is how i can prevent the browser from leaving a domain.

For ex: google.com is open. Browser can redirect to any page from google.com like google.com/index but can't leave google.com

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`WebBrowser.Navigating` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx):

> *"Occurs before the `WebBrowser` control navigates to a new document."*
>
> *"You can handle the `Navigating` event to cancel navigation […]. To cancel navigation, set the `Cancel` property of the `WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs` object passed to the event handler to `true`. You can also use this object to retrieve the URL of the new document through the `WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs.Url` property."*
>
> — [MSDN reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx)

So you should be able to subscribe to your `WebBrowser`'s `Navigating` event, and inside the handler, check the `e.Url` property of the event argument object `e`. If it refers to another domain, set `e.Cancel` to `True` to abort navigation:

```
AddHandler webBrowser.Navigating, AddressOf EnsureWebBrowserStaysInMyDomain
' ^ Note that subscribing a handler method to the `Navigating` event
'   can also be done directly from the Forms Designer, if you prefer.

…

Sub EnsureWebBrowserStaysInMyDomain(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs)
    If e.Url.Host <> "example.com" Then
        e.Cancel = True
        MessageBox.Show(icon:=MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                        text:="You can never leave!",
                        caption:="Hotel California",
                        buttons:=MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)  ' ;-)
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Navigating` and `Navigated` events are one example of a pattern you see quite often in Windows Forms: The events named `…ing` happen *before* something is about to happen; these give you an opportunity to abort the process. The events named `…ed` happen only afterwards.

Note also that the `Navigating` event is only triggered for user interactions. The visited webpages may still include images from other domains, and running scripts can still send HTTP requests to other domains.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will detect if the browser leaves the domain and then go back to the previous page.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        On Error Resume Next
        If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString.Substring(0, Len("https://www.google.com")) <> "https://www.google.com" Or Len(WebBrowser1.Url.ToString) <> Len("https://www.google.com") Then
            WebBrowser1.GoBack()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This code detects if the browser *has already left* the domain. This is not ideal. Instead of letting a new page load, one would ideally prevent navigation to the new page completely. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40563452/240733) for a suggestion how to do this.